# Java: Objects in vectors

Tags: java, oop

```
Vector v = new Vector();
String element = "Object"
v.add(element);

char c = ((String)v.get(0).charAt(0);
```

Why do we need cast the element as `String` to use the methods of the `element` if the references contained by the vector points to the proper object which is `String` now?

Comment: You need to cast because you are not using *Generics*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As @pablochan said and:
Beacuse it's not generics collection get(int index) will return Object. This is also true for generics collection e.g new ArrayList<String>() except generics add type safety during compilation.

Comment: Consider looking for newer tutorials: Vector is a very old and largely deprecated class; generics came in Java 5 (in 2004). Maybe try [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not declaring the element type of the `Vector`, so the compiler assumes that elements are just `Objects`. Try this:

```
Vector<String> = new Vector<>(); // new Vector<String>() if you're using Java6 or older
```

Answer (score 1):

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java
>   Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations,
>   Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed,
>   it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

**Source**: [Java Vector API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

As people above already mentioned, you do not specify what type of `Object` will your `Vector` contain. Therefore, Java assumes the elements in your `Vector` are of type `Object` which is the most generic type. Therefore, you'd be required to cast it into an appropriate type in order to carry out type specific operations.

I would encourage you to go onto the link provided above to learn more about the collection you are planning to use.